# Mutt Gmail Trash behaviour without custom "trash" patch

Tags: mutt

I configured Mutt to correctly move messages to trash in Gmail (instead of just archiving, which seems to be the default behaviour) using the well-known [trash patch](http://cedricduval.free.fr/mutt/patches/#trash):

```
set trash = "imaps://jviottidc@imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Trash"
```

Is there a way to configure Mutt to move messages to my Gmail Trash folder *without* using a custom patch?

I'm running:

```
$ mutt -v
Mutt 1.6.2 (2016-07-01)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version of mutt now incorporates the trash patch, so simply by upgrading to mutt 1.7.0 or later should give you the desired behavior.

From the [ChangeLog for 1.7.0](http://www.mutt.org/doc/UPDATING):

```
  + $trash, when set, specifies the path of the folder where mails
    marked for deletion will be moved, instead of being irremediably
    purged.
  + The  function can be used to delete an entry and
    bypass the trash folder.
```

I've been using the trash patch for a long time (and occasionally updating it to apply to new versions), so this is a welcome addition.